# Facebook picture likes takes too long using FQL or API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm using this script to get the likes of a number of (public) facebook pictures:

```
while ($stmt2->fetch()){
    $fql = 'SELECT like_info from photo WHERE object_id='.$id;
    $friends = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => $fql,
    ));

    //... do stuff

    $i=$i+1;
}
```

The script works fine, but when the picture amount reaches more than 100, the script loads very slow. Probably because every single FQL query takes too much time.

Is their any way I can do this faster? For example make a batch FQL-request or something?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/

Answer (score 0):

It would make much more sense if you generate the FQL statement first, and then calling it once, instead of calling it for each result.

```
SELECT like_info from photo WHERE object_id in ({object_id_1}, {object_id_2}, {...})
```

You'd then just generate the comma-separated list of object_ids.

The "official" endpoint for recent Graph API versions is

```
/fql?q={url_encoded_fql_query}
```

and

```
method: 'get'
```